# including sub-Snakefiles and generate their outputs

Tags: python, include, snakemake

## Problem

The problem is that when I `include` other sub-Snakefiles into the main Snakefile, the output of the sub-Snakefiles are never generated. If this helps, I think of this as having optional "branches" in the pipeline - sometimes my clients want the outputs of a specific branch, and come clients don't. I want to be able to choose when to execute those optional branches. My snakemake version is `5.13.0`.

## Ideal solution

I want to `include` sub-Snakefiles, and have those sub-Snakefile's outputs generated. The following is what I envision:

#### config.yaml

```yaml
module2: "yes"
```

#### Snakefile ('master' snakefile)

```py
# working dir
workdir: "path/to/dir/test"
configfile: "code/config.yaml"

# core rules. These rules are always run. 
include: "code/head.py"

if config["module2"] == "yes":
    include: "code/module2/Snakefile"

rule all:
    input:
        "data/output_head.txt"
```

Where `module2` can e.g. generate a specific graph if my clients request it.

Note that even though the master Snakefile's rule all input hasn't changed, I would like to generate the output of `code/module2/Snakefile` sub-Snakefile. Each of the file contents are shown in the next section.

## My (wrong) approach

REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

```
├── Snakefile
├── code
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── head.py
│   └── module2
│       ├── Snakefile
│       └── tail.py
├── data
└── inputs
    └── test_input.txt
```

**Snakefile ('master' snakefile creates core workflow output)**

```py
# working dir
workdir: "path/to/dir/test"
configfile: "code/config.yaml"

# core rules
include: "code/head.py"

# module 2 rules
include: "code/module2/Snakefile"

# core output
rule all:
    input:
        "data/output_head.txt"
```

**test_input.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**code/head.py**

```py
rule head:
    input:
        "inputs/test_input.txt"
    output:
        "data/output_head.txt"
    shell:
        "head -3 {input} > {output} " # we expect 1 2 3 in output_head.txt
```

**code/module2/Snakefile ('subordinate' snakefile creates optional module 2 output files)**

```py
include: "tail.py"

rule all:
    input:
        "data/output_tail.txt"
```

**code/module2/tail.py**

```py
rule tail:
        input:
                "inputs/test_input.txt"
        output:
                "data/output_tail.txt"
        shell:
                "tail -3 {input} > {output} " # we expect 8 9 10 in output_tail.txt
```

The actual error I run into is:

```
CreateRuleException in line 12 of path/to/dir/test/Snakefile:
The name all is already used by another rule
```

I believe this is because the sub-Snakefile's `rule all` clashes with the master Snakefile's `rule all`.

REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

Lastly I looked into the [Modularization](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html) page, and under `include` it says:

> The default target rule (often called the all-rule), won’t be affected by the include. I.e. it will always be the first rule in your Snakefile, no matter how many includes you have above your first rule.

If I translated this right, it can be reworded as: "including Snakefiles into your main Snakefile will not add new output files because that's determined by the main Snakefile."

If that is true, then what is the point of including sub-Snakefiles if I don't get their output files?

## Conclusion

What would be the best way to set up the pipeline to conditionally `include` sub-Snakefiles and generate their output files? Maybe I'm reading the docs horribly wrong. If I am, then please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best, but here's my solution.  In the config, I have the user specify which 'branches' to include:

```yaml
# config.yaml
main:
    subworkflows:
        - workflow1
        - workflow2
```

The main Snakefile uses this config entry to include other snakefiles with matching names.  Also note that I have additional checks if the name doesn't exist and have per-subworkflow config files that are loaded and merged with some extra script.

```py
# Snakefile
subworkflows = config['main']['subworkflows']
for subw in subworkflows:
    sub_path = 'subworkflows/{}.snake'.format(subw)
    sub_config = 'subworkflows/{}.yaml'.format(subw)
    if not os.path.exists(sub_path):
        continue

    subw_outputs_dict[subw] = []

    if os.path.exists(sub_config):
        configfile: sub_config
        paths = join_config_paths(paths, config['path'])

    include: sub_path

    if len(subw_outputs_dict[subw]) == 0:
        continue

    subw_outputs.extend(subw_outputs_dict[subw])

rule all:
    input:
        subw_outputs
```

And each submodule builds its final output into the subw_outputs_dict, acting as a rule all for each part.

```py
# workflow1.snake
if "subw_outputs_dict" in locals() and "ids" in locals():
    subw_outputs_dict['workflow1'] = expand(paths['my_output'], id=ids)
```

To summarize:

- config.yaml controls what is run
- Snakefile includes the requested workflows and joins them into a single list of files for rule all
- Each sub workflow defines a set of rules and its outputs in a global dictionary.

This was inspired by another project that I can't remember, but it's worked ok for me.  I'd be interested what others have done.  I bet there's a sleeker way to use subworkflows, but I find includes easier to think about and debug.

Comment: To answer your specific questions, the conflict in rule all is what you think, this approach gets around it by having a single rule all in the main Snakefile.  The second part in the documentation means that the first rule in Snakefile is the default.  If you include additional snakefiles above, there are other rules 'before' all, but they aren't set as the default.

Comment: Although it's a hackish way to do it, this solution works and is very readable! I'll mark it as best answer if no one else can contribute another method in the next couple of days.